# property of real matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ with $m \geq n+1$ a real matrix with the property that the euclidean norm of every line is $1$.  That is $A = \begin{bmatrix} A_1^T\\ \vdots A_m^T\end{bmatrix}$ with $\|A_i\| = 1$ $\forall i \in \{1, ... m\}$.

Assume that $rank(A) = n$. I want to prove that every line of 
$$ M = A\cdot \left(A^T \cdot A\right)^{-1} \cdot A^T$$ also has the norm $1$. Is this true? If $A$ would be square then this would be trivial (and maybe it is trivial, but I do not see it right now ... )

Update:

One can see that $M$ is idempotent, and symmetric. It is diagonalizable and its eigenvalues are either $1$ or $0$.

Comment: Try with $A=\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\end{bmatrix}$.